# TezBox won't let me create a KT1 account for delegating

Tags: tezbox, kt1

I'm having an issue with TezBox. I have my ICO wallet there, with the XTZ I bought at this time, and I activated it but never did anything with it. Now I would like to start delegating but for that I have to create a KT1 account. And when I try to do that in TezBox, it says "There was an error adding account. Please ensure your main account has funds available.". Of course there are enough funds, I have more than 1000 XTZ in my account. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: The web platform is giving a similar error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the web platform, they have a bug currently preventing new account creations, see https://twitter.com/TezBox_Wallet/status/1134767700511584257